# "Исковерканный путь к файлу" при ассоциация файлов с программой

Tags: delphi

Вопрос такой. Ассоциировал свою программу с собственными файлами, сделал, чтобы при открытии файла путь к файлу отображался в статус баре. Когда я открываю файл при помощи
`OpenDialog`, путь отображается нормально. Но когда я запускаю собственный файл, путь в статус баре получается каким-то исковерканным, использовать его (путь) в дальнейшем вполне возможно.
Но выглядит он в статус баре ужасно, примерно так `C:\User\CD86~1\Decktop\ и т. д..` Можно ли привести его к нормальному виду?

Функция выглядит так:

```
 function Load(FName: string ):boolean;
    var
    bmp: Tbitmap;
    begin
    bmp:=Tbitmap.Create;
  bmp.LoadFromFile(FName);
  Form1.StatusBar1.Panels[3].Text:=FName;
   bmp.Free;
 end;
```

Процедура так:

```
 procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (ParamCount > 0) and FileExists(ParamStr(1))  then Load(ParamStr(1));
end;
```

Ассоциировал расширение так:

```
 procedure Registration( FileType,        // Тип файла (расширение)
                        FileTypeName,    // Имя
                        Description,     // Описание
                        ExecCommand,     // Путь к запускному файлу
                        Index: string ); // Индекс иконки
var
  reg: TRegistry;
begin
   if ( FileType = '' ) or ( FileTypeName = '' ) or
      ( ExecCommand = '' ) then Exit;
   if FileType[1] <> '.' then FileType := '.' + FileType;
   if Description = '' then Description := FileTypeName;
   reg := TRegistry.Create;
   with Reg do
   begin
      RootKey := HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;
      OpenKey( FileType, true );
      WriteString( '', FileTypeName );
      CloseKey;
      OpenKey( FileTypeName, true );
      WriteString( '', Description );
      CloseKey;
      OpenKey( FileTypeName + '\DefaultIcon', true );
      WriteString( '', ExecCommand + ', ' + Index );
      CloseKey;
      OpenKey( FileTypeName + '\Shell\Open\Command', true );
      WriteString( '', ExecCommand + ' %1' );
   end;
   reg.Free;

end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте [это](http://www.delphimaster.net/view/1-73123).
В целом, есть два способа:

- Превратить короткий путь в длинный
- Зарегистрировать свою программу в реестре так, что бы она получала длинный путь.